# Was Frege's 2nd-order logic a complete system?

Tags: set-theory, incompleteness

Frege's system was found to be inconsistent due to Russell's paradox, due to his Basic Law V, but was Frege's logic complete in any sense?

Godel showed that no consistent formal system can be complete, but what about an inconsistent formal system?

NB: I am taking to Frege's system now to be a paraconsistent system that does not admit the princple of explosion. Any true statement must be derivable by the axioms of the system and not via explosion.

Comment: You can see e.g. Kai F. Wehmeier, [Consistent fragments of grundgesetze and the existence of non-logical objects (1999)](https://philpapers.org/rec/WEHCFO) as well as R.Heck, [The Consistency of Predicative Fragments of Frege's Grundgesetze der Arithmetik (1996)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233104169_The_Consistency_of_Predicative_Fragments_of_Frege's_Grundgesetze_der_Arithmetik) and in general R.Heck's books on Frege's Logicfor detailed discussions of how much of Frege's logic can be salvaged.

Comment: Obviously, Frege was unaware of Goedel's discovery; but we can conjecture that Frege's goal was exactly to formalize a system complete with respect to the standard model of arithmetic.